# Multiple Attributes in SQL CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Query which will compare file_names from web_pub_subfile table and displays information if file is found or no

```
SELECT file_name, CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1
           FROM  web_pub_subfile  t JOIN infocard_1 ic on ic.info_card_id=t.info_card_id
           WHERE  E.file_name = t.file_name and lower(ic.vault_name) ='SU-SPEC-RELEASE') 
           THEN 'YES'
           ELSE 'NO' END AS File_Found
FROM (VALUES 
('00924.dwg'),
('00960.dwg'),
('00973.dwg'),
('00984.dwg'),
('01008.dwg')) E(file_name)
```

I'll get the OUTPUT in this format

```
file_name   File_Found
----------------------
00924.dwg   NO
00960.dwg   YES
00973.dwg   YES
00984.dwg   YES
01008.dwg   YES
```

Can I show 2 more attributes (document_num and vault_name) from TABLE -> web_pub_subfile using ABOVE Query?

```
file_name   File_Found  document_num  vault
-----------------------------------------------------
00924.dwg   NO          Test1         SU-SPEC-RELEASE
00960.dwg   YES         Test2         SU-SPEC-RELEASE
00973.dwg   YES         Test3         SU-SPEC-RELEASE
00984.dwg   YES         Test4         SU-SPEC-RELEASE
01008.dwg   YES         Test5         SU-SPEC-RELEASE
```

Comment: Provide web_pub_subfile and infocard_1 table def.

Comment: How you got `Test1` , `SU-SPEC-RELEASE` in first line even though there is no file found

Comment: @Prdp Second output is just for example. I am trying to get that information from web_pub_subfile TABLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CASE` statement cannot return more than one column

You can move the `sub-query` to `left join`

```
SELECT file_name,
       CASE
         WHEN t.file_name IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES'
         ELSE 'NO'
       END AS File_Found,
       document_num, -- Replace it with the original column name 
       vault_name    -- Replace it with the original column name 
FROM   (VALUES ('00924.dwg'),
               ('00960.dwg'),
               ('00973.dwg'),
               ('00984.dwg'),
               ('01008.dwg')) E(file_name)
       LEFT JOIN web_pub_subfile t
              ON E.file_name = t.file_name
       LEFT JOIN infocard_1 ic
              ON ic.info_card_id = t.info_card_id
                 AND Lower(ic.vault_name) = 'SU-SPEC-RELEASE'
```

Comment: Thanks bro. It worked but had to change last statement

LEFT JOIN infocard_1 ic LEFT JOIN web_pub_subfile t
ON ic.info_card_id = t.info_card_id
AND (Lower(ic.vault_name) = 'SU-SPEC-RELEASE')
ON E.file_name = t.file_name